# how to copy column from one table data to another table and insert more columns same time in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli

I want to know, how to copy a column from one table data to another table in mysql and insert more values at the same time.

**Table 1:**

```
**id:** 1
**Items :** [{"id":"9","size":"64 GB","quantity":"1"},{"id":"9","size":"32 GB","quantity":2},{"id":"1","size":"32","quantity":"1"},{"id":"5","size":"8","quantity":"1"},{"id":"2","size":"38","quantity":"1"}]
**Create_Date:** 31/08/2018
**Exp_date:** 01/09/2018
```

**Table 2:**

```
**id:**
**Order_id:**
**Items:**
**Paid:**
```

I want to copy table 1 items and insert it table 2 and at the same time I want to insert order_id, paid in table 2

For this I am trying this:

```
$order_id = "DJ9JQY4J00248";
$paid = "Order Complete";
$insertSql = "INSERT INTO table2  (`order_id`,`paid`) VALUES ('$order_id','$paid') AND (items) SELECT items FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'";
$db->query($insertSql);
```

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong. The above Code is not working for me.

Comment: if you look items return with ´array´ you need put ´foreach´ on items and pass value to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your variables to select

```
INSERT INTO table2  
    (`order_id`,`paid`, items)  
    SELECT '$order_id','$paid', items FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0008 seconds.)

Comment: How do I insert value of ((`order_id`,`paid`)  $order_id','$paid while copying items from table 1

Comment: Put them in the select list in a proper order, as I show in the answer

Comment: How can I select $order_id, $paid from cart when there are no such columns

Comment: They are not names of columns, they are values. Select wil return it as is. `Select 1 will return 1`